# block Jenkins job until http request returns a certain response

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

is there a plugin that exists to block a Jenkins job(keep a job running) and poll a web service then check the response against regex. if the regex matches then the job will continue?

I know this is possible with a script, but I wanted to use a dedicated plugin if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin: Parameterized Trigger Plugin. It has this option:
When using the "Trigger/Call builds on another project" item.
You have this option available:  "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds"

Comment: that will block the current job until other jobs finish. what I am attempting to do is poll a URL and wait for a certain response. while polling it should block the job from continuing